# Unable to program Atmega128

Tags: embedded, atmega

I am using ATMEGA128L on development board. I am trying to program it using an AVR serial ISP with the help of WinAVR. The changes that i made in makefile are as follows. MCU-atmega128 , programmer-avrisp, port-COM1 ( The port which has been assigned by pc ).The development board is getting proper dc power supply as the default program loaded by the vendor in it is running properly.The error that i am getting is "*avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00*"The connections between programmer and micro-controller are as follows.

connections between programmer and microcontroller

programmer   --  microcontroller

MOSI     ---      PE0

MISO     --      PE1

SCK      --      SCK(PB1)

RST      --      RST of board

VCC      --     VCC of Dev board

GND      --     GND of dev board

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because without further information this seems to be a hardware problem.

Comment: Is there no chipselect required for SPI?